# when upgrading vb6 project to visual basic express 8?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a vb6 project that is made up  of using **3rd party** control(like atalasoft imaging sdk), now i am upgrading that project causes an error, Now i remove that error from editing the **.vbp** file(i delete the reference from **.vbp**) , project is upgraded but we have some errors regarding that deleted dll in **.vbp** file, **Now i am asking is it possible to add that dll in upgraded vb8 project.**

thanks in advance.

Comment: i am using windows 8.1

Comment: No. VB 6 is the end of the line. Upgrading to a newer version of VB is "upgrading" to an entirely different, incompatible language. Your old 3rd-party controls will not work.

Comment: at this stage what can i do for 3rd party control?